# How do I prevent SimpleSecurityManager being used in JackRabbit?

Tags: jackrabbit

How I stop Jackrabbit using SimpleSecurityManager?

I'm trying to call session.getUserManager() but I get a repository exception as SimpleSecurityManager.getUserManager() explicity throws it.

```
<Security appName="Jackrabbit">
    <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
    </SecurityManager>

    <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleAccessManager">
        <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/access.xml"/> -->
    </AccessManager>

    <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule">
       <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
       <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
    </LoginModule>
</Security>
```

Rest of code for those that will ask...

```
Repository repository = new TransientRepository();
Session jackrabbitSession = repository.login(credentials);
UserManager userManager = session.getUserManager();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user manager is a Jackrabbit extension.  It's not a part of the JCR.  So, you need to use a JackrabbitSession, not just a Session.  Here's a link to the wiki:

http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/UserManagement